# Pyramid: OperationalError 1054, "Unknown column 'XX' in 'field list'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

When trying to access the database, I am unable to access the column.  I have run the init database script multiple times. Here's the code:

View

```
from .models import Session, Admin
@view_config(route_name='admin', renderer='templates/admin.pt')
def admin(request):
    session = Session()
    user = authenticated_userid(request)
    admin = bool(session.query(Admin).filter_by(username = user).first())
    message = ''
    if admin:
        if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
            session.add(Admin(request.params['admin']))
            session.commit()
            message = "%s has been added as an Admin!" % request.params['admin']
            return dict(url=request.route_url('admin'),
                        message = message,
                    )
        return dict(message = message)
    else:
        return HTTPForbidden()
```

Models

```
class Admin(Base):
    __tablename__='admins'
    __table_args__={
        'mysql_engine':'InnoDB',
        'mysql_charset':'utf8',
    }

    username = Column(String(255), ForeignKey('users.username'), primary_key=True)

    def __init(self, user):
        self.username = user
```

Comment: For those who are wondering, what I did was modify the init db script to drop all tables with Base.metadata.drop_all(engine) function, and it drops all tables, instead of database itself, making it much quicker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The database script can't add column on an already existing table. If you modified or added the column after running the script, that's where your problem come from.

You have three possibilities :

- Delete the database and let the script recreate it the right way
- Run the sql to add the column by hand.
- Take a look at [Alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), which can help you do that automatically.

Comment: Is there no possibility of overlaying the database so we don't have to touch actual schema columns?